# wxpython: pause code as long as second frame is open

Tags: python, pycharm, event-handling, wxpython, frame

I'm pretty much a Python beginner and have only recently started with wxpython and now have the following question:

I'm writing an application where one window is open and by clicking a button, the user opens a second window, where they're supposed to input their name and click another button. My problem is that I don't know how to pause the 'event code' that is executed by clicking *Button1* until the user is done with their actions in the second window.

Is there a way to pause the code in *OnButton1* (after the line `secondframe.Show()` until the user has input their name in the *SecondFrame* and clicked on *OnButton2*?

Essentially my goal is that first, the name of the user is printed and only afterwards, *Done* is printed

```
class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.Button1 = wx.Button(self.panel, label='Button 1', pos=(20, 10), size=(90, 25))

        #Set event handlers
        self.Button1.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnButton1)

    def OnButton1(self, e):
        secondframe = SecondFrame(None)
        secondframe.Show()
        print("Done")



class SecondFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.Button2 = wx.Button(self.panel, label='Button 2', pos=(50, 20), size=(90, 25))
        self.NameBox = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, value="Type Your Name", pos=(50, 60), size=(200, -1))


        #Set event handlers
        self.Button2.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnButton2)

    def OnButton2(self, e):
        Name = self.NameBox.GetValue()
        print(Name)


app = wx.App(False)
frame = MainFrame(None)
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Common dialog classes and functions encapsulate commonly-needed dialog box requirements. They are all ‘modal’, grabbing the flow of control until the user dismisses the dialog, to make them easy to use within an application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a way to actually block the code there. (Also, blocking is generally speaking never a good idea.)
But you can get the same behaviour like this:

- Where you open the second window, in the first Window you call `self.Disable()`
- When creating the second window, you also hand a reference to the first window to it (i.e. `secondframe = SecondFrame(None, self)`), adjust the constructor (`def __init__(self, parent, main):`) and store this in a variable there (`self.mainFrame = main`).
- You add a method to MainFrame, e.g. `reenable(self)`
- there you call `self.Enable()`
- When you're done with Frame two, you can simply call `self.mainFrame.reenable()`

All in all, that would make something like:

```py
class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.Button1 = wx.Button(self.panel, label='Button 1', pos=(20, 10), size=(90, 25))

        #Set event handlers
        self.Button1.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnButton1)

    def OnButton1(self, e):
        secondframe = SecondFrame(None, self)
        self.Disable()
        secondframe.Show()

    def reenable(self):
        self.Enable()
        print("done")



class SecondFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, main):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.mainFrame = main

        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.Button2 = wx.Button(self.panel, label='Button 2', pos=(50, 20), size=(90, 25))
        self.NameBox = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, value="Type Your Name", pos=(50, 60), size=(200, -1))


        #Set event handlers
        self.Button2.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnButton2)

    def OnButton2(self, e):
        Name = self.NameBox.GetValue()
        print(Name)
        self.mainFrame.reenable()


app = wx.App(False)
frame = MainFrame(None)
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: looks good! I had a similar idea but wasn't sure how to execute it, thanks!

Comment: My pleasure. In reality you probably want to re-enable the first window on close, rather than on button click. Another way of implementing it would be to make the second window a custom dialog and show it modal - this may be easier if it has a short lifetime, but for a longer lifetime a frame is probably the right call.